# how to post video on fb timeline using share dialog with javascript sdk?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have developed one application. I have  to upload video on fb timeline,  from developed  application trough Facebook JavaScript sdk with help of FB.ui method.

i have shared part of my code, which i tried to post video on facebook timeline.when i used this code, video get upload as a link. it will navigate to new tab and play when i click on that link.(my video type is mp4.)

```
            FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                display: 'popup',
                type:'mp4',     
                source:filePath,
                picture:filePath,
 },function (response) {               
                if (response && !response.error_message) {
                    alert('Posting completed.');
                } else {
                    alert('Error while posting.');
                }
```

I expect the video to be play on my timeline instead of posting as a link.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect the video to be play on my timeline instead of posting as a link.

That expectation is simply unfounded – this isn’t supposed to work this way, and never has.

You would need to share a link to an HTML document, that has the video embedded via Open Graph meta tags, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#video

But Facebook has begun limiting the occasions on which they actually play such videos inline; so even if you implement this properly and technically correct, there is no guarantee any more it will play in news feed; users clicking on such a post might simply get redirected to your external site to play the video there.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i have tried via **Open Graph meta tags too**, still it is sharing link only. could u help me with the bit of code which has implemented via  **Open Graph**.

Comment: The debug tool can tell you whether you implemented the tags correctly. Again, there is no guarantee any more that Facebook will play your video inline, so there isn’t much more you can do than that.